# C/C++ Variadic Macro Function Overloading

Tags: c++, c, variadic-functions, variadic-macros

I am trying to build a simple c++ logger for learning purposes, but I seem to be stuck at the following issue. Let's say that I have a namespace that contains two functions as follows:

```cpp
namespace l {
    void _p(const char* file, const int line, int vl, const char* fmt, ...) {
        printf("%d:%s:%d: ", vl, file, line);
        va_list __args;
        va_start(__args, fmt);
        vfprintf(stdout, fmt, __args);
        printf("\n");
        va_end(__args);
    }
    void _p(const char* file, const int line, const char* fmt, ...) {
        printf("%s:%d: ", file, line);
        va_list __args;
        va_start(__args, fmt);
        vfprintf(stdout, fmt, __args);
        printf("\n");
        va_end(__args);
    }
}
```

and the main function is as follows:

```cpp
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    l::_p(__FILE__, __LINE__, 12, "%s", "Hello World!");
    l::_p(__FILE__, __LINE__, "%s", "Hello World!");
    return 0;
}
```

what I would like to have is a macro such that when the user types: `l::p(12, "%s", "Hello World!");` it would be replaced by `l::_p(__FILE__, __LINE__, 12, "%s", "Hello World!");` at compile time. Similarly when the user types `l::p("%s", "Hello World!");` it would be replaced by `l::_p(__FILE__, __LINE__, "%s", "Hello World!");` at compile time

Comment: `vfprintf(stdout, fmt, __args);` is invalid when `fmt` is `NULL`.

Comment: edited to remove `fmt=NULL`

Comment: Variadic functions are both burdensome and dangerous, nothing good comes out of them. Consider either taking a single struct/class as input, or to implement a number of overloaded functions corresponding to the accepted formats instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what I would like to have is a macro such that when the user types: `l::p(12, "%s", "Hello World!");` it would be replaced by `l::_p(__FILE__, __LINE__, 12, "%s", "Hello World!");` at compile time.

Sure, you can do:

```
#define p(...)  _p(__FILE__, __LINE__, __VA_ARGS__)
```

Macros are processed at preprocessing stage at which point compiler is not aware about anything complicated like namespace. So such a macro can be confusing to unaware programmers that will later try to define a function named `p` or call a function pointer named `p`.

Preferably in C++ use stream-like interface with a macro instead like `BOOST_LOG` does for example, (and since C++20 you could use [source_location](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/source_location)).

Comment: I have also replaced all instances of `l::p(...)` with `l_p(...)` to prevent macro replacement when there is already a function defined as `p(...)`

Answer (score 0):

Use a logging macro

```
#define LOG(...) l::_p(__FILE__, __LINE__, __VA_ARGS__)

void f(int i) {
    LOG(12, "%d", i);
    LOG("%d", i);
}
```